# How to suspend the main command when piping the output to another delay command

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, xargs

I have two custom scripts to implement their own tasks, one for outputting some URLs (pretend as `cat` command below) and another for receiving a URL to parse it via network requests (pretend as `sleep` command below).

Here is the prototype:

Case 1:

```sh
cat urls.txt | xargs -I{} sleep 1 && echo "END: {}"
```

The output is `END: {}` and the `sleep` works.

Case 2:

```sh
cat urls.txt | xargs -I{} echo "BEGIN: {}" && sleep 1 && echo "END: {}"
```

The output is

```
BEGIN: https://www.example.com/1
BEGIN: https://www.example.com/2
BEGIN: https://www.example.com/3
END: {}
```

but it seems only `sleep` 1 second.

Q1: I'm a little confused, why are these outputs?

Q2: Are there any solutions to execute the full pipelined `xargs` delay command for every `cat` line output?

Comment: read `man xargs` and check out the description of `-I`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for shellter and UtLox's reminder, I found the `xargs` is the key.

Here is my finding, the shell/zsh interpreter splits the `sleep 5` and `echo END: {}` as another serial of commands, so `xargs` didn't receive my expected two `&&` inline commands as one utility command and replace the `{}` with value in the `END` expression. This could be proved by `xargs -t`.

```sh
cat urls.txt | xargs -I{} -t echo "BEGIN: {}" && sleep 1 && echo "END: {}"
```

Inspired by UtLox's the answer, I found I could join my expectation with `sh -c` in `xargs`.

```sh
cat urls.txt | xargs -I{} -P 5 sh -c 'echo "BEGIN: {}" && sleep 1 && echo "END: {}"'
```

For the `-P 5`, it makes the utility commmand ran with max specified subprocesses in parallel mode to make use of most bandwide resources.

Done!

Answer (score 2):

You can put the commands into a separate script:

**worker.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "BEGIN: $*" && sleep 1 && echo "END: $*"
```

set execute permission:

```
chmod +x worker.sh
```

and call it with xargs:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -I{} ./worker.sh {}
```

**output**

```
BEGIN: https://www.example.com/1
END: https://www.example.com/1
BEGIN: https://www.example.com/2
END: https://www.example.com/2
BEGIN: https://www.example.com/3
END: https://www.example.com/3
```

Between BEGIN and END the script sleep for one second.

Comment: I found that group command could be inlined as `xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "BEGIN: {}" && sleep 1 && echo "END: {}"'` briefly. Thanks for your tips!